# JSON to CSV conversion - python

Tags: python, json, csv

I have tried to find a solution, but none seem to be working. I'm trying to convert a JSON file into a CSV file. Here is the JSON format.

```
[
{
    "entity_id":  "9AEA-09FECFA87339",
    "product":  "SLF_PRED",
    "managing_server_id":  "334841-854A-ECC259F48439",
    "ad_domain":  "",
    "folder_path":  "HOME",
    "ip_address_list":  "10.21.111.226",
    "mac_address_list":  "00-21-51-00-RD-32",
    "host_name":  "PREMLAPTOP",
    "isolation_status":  "not_supported",
    "capabilities":  [

                     ]
},
```

And here is the code I'm using:

```
    import json
    import csv

    #read file
    with open('test.json', 'r') as jsonfile:
    data=jsonfile.read()

    # parse file
    jsonobj = json.loads(data)

    def jsontocsv(input_json, output_path):
    keylist = []
    for key in jsonobj[0]:
      keylist.append(key)
    f = csv.writer(open(output_path, "w"))
    f.writerow(keylist)

    for record in jsonobj:
     currentrecord = []
     for key in keylist:
      currentrecord.append(record[key])
    f.writerow(currentrecord)

    jsontocsv(jsonobj,'test.csv')
```

When I run this - nothing happens.

Comment: Please format your code correctly

Comment: What's your expected output for this JSON file?

Comment: The expected output would be a csv with 10 columns where the headers correspond to the left column in the JSON data above.

Answer (score 0):

If it's formatted correctly, it should write a file called "test.csv" to the same folder where the python script is running.